# How do I access a field inside a subquery within a subquery?

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `o`.`price`,
       `us`.`avatar` AS `url`,
       `u`.`id`,
       `u`.`username`
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id` =
  (SELECT user_id
   FROM
     (SELECT s.vol,
             t_vol,
             user_id
      FROM orders s
      LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT Sum(vol) AS t_vol,
                order_id
         FROM order_transactions
         GROUP BY order_id) t ON s.id = t.order_id
      WHERE o.price = s.price HAVING vol - Ifnull(t_vol, 0) > 0) adsads
   ORDER BY s.vol DESC LIMIT 1)
INNER JOIN `user_settings` AS `us` ON `us`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`price` IN (10.00000000)
GROUP BY `o`.`price`
```

I know it's a big one, but the issue is quite simple. `o.price` (`WHERE o.price = s.price` on the 5th to last line) isn't accessible because it is inside a nested subquery. I really don't know how to fix this, making an alias for `o.price` does not help.

Edit: I found out that I need a correlated subquery. Any ideas on how to restructure my query are much appreciated.

Edit 2: Here's a description of what I need to do...

- Compute the *remaining volume* of every single order
- For each distinct price, find the avatar of the user who owns the order with the largest *remaining volume*

**Remaining volume:** Each order can have zero or more order_transactions. The remaining volume of an order is the original volume of that order minus the sum of all order_transactions belonging to that order.

---

**SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52a3d5**

Comment: I'm sure this query could definitely be refactored quite a bit. For one MySQL is better at optimizing `join`s than subqueries so you wanna use those when possible. Could you give the table structure and explain in plain English which user you're trying to select? It seems something like the user with the largest order volume but it's not entirely clear from just the query.

Comment: It is the user with the largest remaining order volume at each price. The remaining volume of an order is calculated by subtracting the sum of order transactions related to that order from the original volume of that order. (volume in the orders table never changes) ie. o.vol - SUM(ot.vol)

Comment: Could you maybe use [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to have a (simplified) version of the data-structure?

Comment: added a SqlFiddle and some extra info

Comment: So if there are 2 entirely different orders that happen to have the same price, you wanna have only the order with the largest remaining volume and then get the user with avatar for that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think this is a rather ugly query but I don't see any other way to do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT prices.price, u.id, u.username, us.avatar AS url
FROM (
  SELECT mo.price, MIN(mo.user_id) u_id
  FROM (
    SELECT p.price, MAX(p.is_left) max_left
    FROM (
      SELECT o.price, o.vol - SUM(IFNULL(t.vol, 0)) is_left
      FROM orders o 
      LEFT JOIN order_transactions t on t.order_id = o.id
      GROUP BY o.price, o.vol, o.id
    ) p
    GROUP BY p.price
  ) m
  JOIN (
    SELECT o.id, o.user_id, o.price, o.vol - SUM(IFNULL(t.vol, 0)) is_left
    FROM orders o 
    LEFT JOIN order_transactions t on t.order_id = o.id
    GROUP BY o.id, o.user_id, o.price, o.vol
  ) mo ON mo.price = m.price AND mo.is_left = m.max_left
  GROUP BY mo.price
) prices
JOIN users u ON u.id = prices.u_id
JOIN user_settings us ON us.user_id = u.id
```

So I'm getting all the orders with what's left for transaction, then getting the `MAX()` per price. Then I'm getting all the orders again and `JOIN`ing on price and on the is_left being the same as the just-determined `MAX(is_left)`. This could be more than 1 result, so I get the `MIN(user_id)` and `GROUP BY` price. Then join on this `MIN(user_id)` to finally have 1 user per price.

Here's the **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6ca/14)** I made, I've added an order for a different price to test.